# my iPhone keeps losing wifi connection. Why is this?

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, router

My laptop connects to my Wifi but my iPhone does not. I connect my macbook air from the basement to the wifi and i get all 3 bars, but then i connect my iPhone from same place in the basement, the iPhone keeps losing the wifi.i had an iphone 4 before so I thought it was just the Antennas of the iPhone 4 that was weak. Now I have the iPhone 6 plus and its the same issue. what do you think is the problem? is it my router? i have a netgear WNR1000v2 and it is upstairs, about 50-60 ft away from my room in the basement.

Comment: Please specify within your original question if you are comparing Wi-Fi accessibility from the exact same point? Which channel your Wi-Fi router is using? Which main obstacles are between your router and your iPhone (concrete ground…)?

Answer (score -1):

Download a wifi analyser onto your phone (plenty of good free ones) and check the signal strength your getting on it when scanning for WAP's.

This should help you rule out if its the signal strength, leaving either your netgear or iPhone as the culprit.

See this article as well

http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/ios-8-problems/2/

Comment: The link provided doesn't lead to a page about Wi-Fi problem analysis. On the other hand it is overloaded with heavy advertising, and the number of cookies loaded is awful. I suggest you to choose a better reference.